# Is there a header that provides types similar to uint64_t for floats and doubles in Linux or gcc?

Tags: linux, gcc, types, floating-point, header-files

I'm wondering if there's a header that provides types similar to `uint64_t` for floats and doubles in Linux or gcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While C doesn't mandate IEEE-754 floating-point, for all intents and purposes, it's universal - like 2's complement arithmetic.

With that assumption, the `<float.h>` header has the macro definitions: `FLT_MANT_DIG` and `DBL_MANT_DIG`, the number of bits in the mantissa. A value of (24) means a 32-bit, single-precision, IEEE-754 floating point type. A value of (53) means a 64-bit double-precision type.

Note however, the 'float' and 'double' types can be the same, even with an IEEE-754 conforming implementation. 'long double' types are frequently aliases for 'double' on many platforms.

Answer (score 2):

"float" and "double" will generally suffice. They map to 32-bit and 64-bit types on every system I've ever used, regardless of the platform's native word size.

Comment: I've used a system (a Cray T90 vector machine) where both `float` and `double` are 64 bits.